# Does the natural atomic orbital analysis result in natural electron configurations of molecules?

Tags: computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, orbitals

In my understanding, the natural atomic orbital (NAO) analysis is a method of calculation to get occupancy of electrons in center of each atoms. In other words, the result of NAO-occupancy indicates the electron configuration about a non-bonded molecule. More specifically, electrons are rearranged in each atom according to the surroundings of such atoms within a molecular configuration.

In this way of understanding, is it correct to say the data in table is result of the NAO analysis?

And, have I no misconception about NAO method?

Comment: NAO means "Natural Atomic Orbital"? Seems a rather obscure method. From what book do you have the table?

Comment: Yes, it is the "Natural atomic orbital" method. It might be more correct to say that it is useful to calculate local populations, rather than configurations. The method is not widely used per se (as far as I know) because it has a strictly local character, which doesn't describe correctly bonding and delocalization, but it is involved, for instance, in the first steps of the NBO algorithm

Comment: Please add a citation for the table you are using. Not quoting the source material properly is plagiarism.